Topic Authorization failed for Kafka after SpringBoot 3/ Java 17 upgrade
I upgraded a service to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.2.2 and now each of its 15 consumers fail with the error message - Topic authorization failed for topics [set.of.topic.names]
I did not change anything related to authorization. The only modification to Kafka is that it needed to also be upgraded alongside it- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka to 3.1.2 and org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients to 3.6.1
We have other services that have successfully made the same upgrade from Java 8 and SpringBoot 2.7 and none of them had this problem. I am using the same versions.
